# Why for loop is splitting strings of user input?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why looping over the user input results splits the values inserted?

```
text = ("Insert something: ")
inputs = raw_input(text).strip("\n")

for i in inputs:
    print i
```

**Results**

```
Insert something: 01 02 03
0
1

0
2

0
3
```

**expected result:**

```
01
02
03
```

Comment: Because you are iterating over a string, so character by character. Why would it magically split on spaces?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strings are *sequences*, containing individual characters. You are iterating over the `inputs` string, so you get the individual characters.

If you wanted to iterate over a list of whitespace-separated words you should first split the string into a list:

```
for i in inputs.split():
```

The `.strip('\n')` call on the result of `raw_input()` is redundant for two reasons:

- `raw_input()` returns the entered string without a newline, so there is no need to remove a newline character here.
- the [`str.split()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), without arguments, splits on arbitrary-length whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines, etc.) and removes whitespace at the start and end. So even if there *was* a newline to remove, `str.split()` would take care of this for you.

Comment: Oh, shame on me, I should had waited a little longer before posting this question.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you just mixed up split() and strip()?

```
text = ("Insert something: ")
inputs = raw_input(text).split(" ")

for i in inputs:
    print i
```

Comment: There's a chance, since i have another function that I wrote in the past that handles user inputs correctly. Maybe it was lack of morning coffee